# How to add event handler to a child component that renders multiple results?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, parent-child

[Parent component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqoMB.png)
[Child Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlC3a.png)
I'm trying to achieve a functionality such as :
I have a parent button(Questions) on click of which a child component will be rendered.
The child component returns multiple results(All questions as buttons) that are fetched from a database.Now clicking each button I should be able to get the entire question data :question edited at,updated at,title,description etc.

Can anyone please help this is the first time I'm working on react.

I tried adding event handler in the child component  render method but that doesn't work.
I tried searching for the solution but could not get one.If I can achieve this using lifting up state how would I achieve it.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you share some code with us :)

Comment: I have added screenshots please check them out.

Comment: Ok, I think I know  what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're displaying multiple questions as `button`s that you fetch in your Child Component and you would like to catch the entire *question* Object when the user clicks a button.

What you need to do is pass the question Object to your `handleQues` function.

Child Component

```
  render(){
    //Rest of your code
    {content.map((p, index) => {
      return (
        <span key={index}>
          <button onClick={this.handleQues.bind(this, p)}>
            {p.title}
          </button>
          <br />
        </span>
       );
     })
    //Rest of your code
  }
```

In your `handleQues` you would have something like this

```
  handleQues (button) {
    console.log(button);
    //Rest of your code

  }
```

**Note:** I'm using `bind` to pass the `p` Object to your `handleQues` but you can also use an arrow function, so your button will look something like this

```
  <button onClick={() => this.handleQues(p)}>
```

Comment: Sir,Thank You so much it worked this way .:) I was making a mistake in binding.